# VBA copy and past rows to different workbooks when condition is met

Tags: vba, excel, loops, conditional-statements, matching

The goal would be to specify two different conditions and whenever either one of those are met the whole row from the masterfile(thisworkbook) would be copied and then pasted to new workbook.

I think that the issues has something to do with the "if" function, since this code works just fine with one condition (creates new workbook and add all the rows to this workbook whenever the condition is met).

Another issues:
This method is quite time consuming when masterfile contains many observations that are in line with the specified condition. For this reason, I would appreciate if someone could come up with better solution on this matter. Instead of pasting rows one by one it would be awesome if all the rows could be posted on correct workbook at once.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    'creating new workbooks
    Dim newDataOne As Workbook
    Dim newDataTwo As Workbook
    Set newDataOne = Workbooks.Add
    Set newDataTwo = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Dim nameone As String
    Dim nametwo As String
    nameone = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("CQ21")
    nametwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("CQ22")
    For i = 10 To a
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nameone Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            newDataOne.ActiveSheet.Activate
            b = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            newDataOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            newDataTwo.ActiveSheet.Activate
            h = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            newDataTwo.ActiveSheet.Cells(h + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

>

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nameone Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            newDataOne.ActiveSheet.Activate
            b = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            newDataOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End If
```

Instead of making two `If Then` statements you can use `Or` to specify two conditions. If either conditions are met, the row is copied and pasted.

Regarding the time it takes to run the code, you should generally avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`, which you do a lot. Try to see if you can come up with a way to avoid this on your own - if you can't I'll help you later today.

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I guess I wasn't explaining the needed outcome as clear as needed. I would need to paste the row (i) from masterfile to different workbook (newDataOne in case first condition is met and newDataTwo if second condition) depending on the condition that is met.

Comment: Okay I see. Is one of the two conditions always met? Futhermore what happens when you run the code. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Nope neither of the conditions are always met and I didn't receive any error messages whatsoever.

Comment: Hmm i can't figure out why it doesn't work. Perhaps you can try making an `If Then Else` statement where the `Else` part is a new `If Then` statement containing the second condition. I doubt it will change anything though.

Answer (score 0):

I could't find any error regarding the second "if". I suggest checking if the value of `CQ22` is a error, for example.

Try to avoid Activate and Select to improve the time to run the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    'creating new workbooks
    Dim newDataOne As Workbook
    Dim newDataTwo As Workbook
    Set newDataOne = Workbooks.Add
    Set newDataTwo = Workbooks.Add
    Dim nameone As String
    Dim nametwo As String
    nameone = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("CQ21")
    nametwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("CQ22")
    For i = 10 To a
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nameone Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            b = newDataOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            newDataOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            h = newDataTwo.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            newDataTwo.ActiveSheet.Cells(h + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Perhaps there indeed was some issues with active and select- commands, since this works just fine now! However, this method is quite heavy in case there are more than two workbooks or lot of observations to be pasted. Could you come up with any suitable solution on this matter (let's say I would have five different conditions and workbooks, respectively)? I haven't used vba at all, but would it be possible to save the row indexes on some sort of arraylist, instead of pasting those one by one?

Comment: If you need only the row indexes instead of pasting the row, you can do something like this: 
        `Dim c1 As New Collection
        Dim c2 As New Collection
        For i = 10 To a
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nameone Then c1.Add (i)
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then c2.Add (i)
    Next i`

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know how I could further select those rows which are included in the collection? This would make the whole method way faster.

Comment: You can write all the indexes in a string and then use them as a range. `Dim r As String
    
    For Each c In c1
        If (r = "") Then
            r = c & ":" & c
        Else
            r = r & "," & c & ":" & c
        End If
    Next
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range(r).Select`